# How to write a powershell function that wraps a sed/perl/etc command

Tags: powershell

I have a number of sed/perl/etc "one-liner" commands that I use frequently:

- `head -1` (Print the first line of a file)
- `sed $d` (Drop the last line of a file)
- `perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)'` (Number lines in a file)

You get the idea.

All of these commands have the same behaviour - they can take input from standard input, or work on a series of files whose names are passed as arguments. I'd like to wrap these common scripts up as Powershell functions, so that I don't have to remember the exact syntax to use. However, aliases don't work like that, and if I do the "obvious" approach with functions:

```
function numlines {
    perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)' $args
}
```

it works with files as arguments (`numlines my_file.pl`) but not with input from a pipe (`cat my_file.pl | numlines`).

Is there a way to write the function so that it works both ways?

To clarify - I can use bat files to do this. For example, numlines.bat containing

```
@perl -pe "$_ = qq($. $_)" %*
```

but having to invoke cmd.exe and the general ugliness of bat files (that "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" prompt when you hit CTRL-C :-() makes me wish for a similarly simple solution within Powershell...

---

Based on Richard's suggestion below, I tried:

```
function test {
  [CmdletBinding()]

  param(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $data
  )

  process {
    perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)'
  }
}
```

If I then do `test file.txt` (which I'd want to run effectively identically to `perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)' file.txt`) the function runs, but waits for data on standard input rather than processing `file.txt`. The same thing happens when I try `cat file.txt | test` - which I'd expect to act identically to `cat file.txt | perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)'`.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your original question but try `wc -l` to count the number of lines in a file. It'll take input from a pipe or you can specify the filename directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the key to the solution is to use $args (for the command line arguments) and $input (for the pipe input) together in the function, as follows:

```
function wrapper {
    $input | WRAPPED_COMMAND_HERE $args
}
```

So, for example, the case of the perl command to number lines looks like this

```
PS> function nl {
>>    $input | perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)' $args
>>  }
>>
PS> nl test.txt
1 This is some
2 test data
PS> type test.txt | nl
1 This is some
2 test data
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Basics: Advanced Functions Can Do More than Standard Functions

> Is there a way to write the function so that it works both ways?

Yes, using [advanced functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx), the process block will be called for each input object.

- You need to specify [`[CmdletBinding]`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847872.aspx) at the start immediately before the `param` block.
- You need a parameter that will take pipeline input, this is done with the [`Parameter`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) attribute on that parameter.

Like this:

```
function ReadInput {
  [CmdletBinding]
  param(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $data
  )

  process {
    "Input was: $data";
  }
}
```

---

#### Better to Do Things Natively

> head -1 (Print the first line of a file)

Look at the `First` parameter of `Select-Object`: `... | Select -f 1 | ....` will just pass the first object through.

> sed $d (Drop the last line of a file)

This one is harder... essentially a function that keeps track if there is another line.

> perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)' (Number lines in a file)

You need `Measure-Object`, which without other parameters will count the number of objects it receives on the pipeline.

---

#### Why It Isn't Working

(Based on the expanded question)

There are two parts to this:

First: you need to pass the value of the parameter bound to the pipeline into you operation. So:

> ```
> process {
>   perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)'
> }
> ```

should be

```
process {
  $data | perl -pe '$_ = qq($. $_)'
}
```

Second: this probably won't work for a lot of your utilities, because each time the `process` block is executed a new instance of the pipeline will be execute, including a new invocation of `sed` (etc.) for each object on the pipeline and thus losing any state your would normally expect it to maintain from one line to the next.

There are two routes around this. First you could use *steppable pipelines*, which is an advanced topic (and the only decent coverage is in the book *Windows PowerShell in Action* Second edition by Bruce Payette (who did most of the PSH language design and implementation)).

Second: do things natively. Eg. number of lines in a file (without using `Measure-Object`):

```
function Get-ObjectCount {
  [CmdletBinding]
  param(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [object[]]$data   # Accept an array...
  )

  begin {
    $count = 0  # Not strictly needed: PSH will default this.
  }

  process {
    $count += $data.length
  }

  end {
    $count
  }
}
```

This will also be much faster (no need to create another process.

As long as you are focused on PSH as a wrapper you are going to find you are gettiong the worst of both worlds: losing the flexibility of the *ix type tools (PSH's execution model is different: cooperating tools in one process) *and* losing the flexibility of PSH (PSH works on *typed objects* not strings).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - those were examples. What I want is *not* to rewrite the code using Powershell, but simply to "wrap" the existing command line (unchanged!) in a function that acts as a named equivalent. It's what the Unix bash shell can do with aliases - `alias firstline='head -1'` but Powershell aliases can't do because they cannot take arguments.

Comment: @PaulMoore: See the first part of the answer (before the horizontal line): how to write functions that can take input on the pipeline or from parameters.

Comment: @PaulMoore: What didn't work? (I suspect you might need to accumulate the input and pass it all to `sed` (each time you execute `sed` a new process will be created).

Comment: I edited the question to give an example of what I'm doing based on your suggestion and what I'd expect (and what I'm actually seeing).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, the approach fundamentally just does not work - adding "$data |" to the process block, pipes each line of the input to a *separate* instance of perl (so the line numbering example fails totally, as it numbers each line as line 1). Also, if I put a filename as an argument, Powershell treats the filename as the data to pipe in, rather than treating it as an argument to the command (That's what the %* is for in the bat file example).

Comment: OK, so it's looking very much like Powershell is fundamentally unable to interoperate well with legacy commands in this way. That's very sad, but not unsurprising based on the way documentation and general practice is to implement things natively rather than reuse existing tools. Unless someone comes up with a solution we haven't thought of, I'm going to assume the answer is "you cannot do this" :-(

Comment: @PaulMoore: PSH can do it, it is just that "Steppable Pipelines" are a somewhat advanced feature that I'm not particularly familiar with (effectively you create a pipeline and then control what goes into it independently of the normal execution order). Note I said this would be needed in the earlier edit.

Comment: Hmm. After doing some more digging, it looks like the answer is far more simple than any of this. I just use $args and $input. I'll post the approach I discovered as a separate answer. If there's anything subtle I've missed, please let me know! I'm somewhat surprised that it *is* this simple...